# Convert a string[] to its associated array of enums

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, enums

I have a string array which its items are string equivalent of an enum items:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    item1,
    item2,
    item3,
    ...
}

string[] strArray = {"item2", "item3"};
```

How to convert `strArray` from `string[]` to `MyEnum[]` by linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyEnum[] enumArray = strArray.Select(s => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), s))
                             .Cast<MyEnum>()
                             .ToArray();
```

Alternatively, if those strings come from user input, you may want to use `Enum.TryParse` instead.

Comment: @KonradKokosa correct, fixed :)

Comment: I think you can move the cast, and just do: `strArray.Select(s => (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), s)).ToArray();` (just as an alternative syntax).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yup, I prefer calling `Cast<T>` myself, it leverages the clarity and readability of functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string[] strArray = { "item2", "item3" };

        MyEnum[] results = (from item in strArray
            let parsed = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), item)
            select parsed).ToArray();
```

You can also skip the parsed sub step line completely ...

```
        MyEnum[] results2 = (from item in strArray
            select (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), item)).ToArray();
```

Comment: You are creating an `object[]`, not a `MyEnum[]` as desired.

Comment: Answer updated; missed a cast on the return of the Enum.Parse

Comment: Yes, or `.Cast<MyEnum>()` before `ToArray` (as shown in  dcastro's answer).

Comment: Indeed. Both are acceptable, it just comes down to personal preference on clarity or code base coding standards/guidelines which are being followed :-)